# PyQT close and reopen application

Tags: python, pyqt

The button in following code is supposed to close the programm window and reopen it. The RESTART part works perfectly well in a different context, but I can´t get it working in this one. 
Any idea what I am missing here? Help from more experient folks would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.win_widget = WinWidget(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.win_widget)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 450, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')  
        self.setWindowIcon (QtGui.QIcon('logo.png'))
        self.show()

class WinWidget (QtGui.QWidget) : 

    def __init__(self, parent): 

        super (WinWidget , self).__init__(parent)
        self.controls()
        self.grid_layout() 

    def controls(self):

        self.btn_newSearch = QtGui.QPushButton('New Search  ', self)
        self.btn_newSearch.clicked.connect(self.restart)
        self.btn_newSearch.setFont(QtGui.QFont('CourierNew', 12 , QtGui.QFont.Bold,False))

    def restart(self):
        self.close()
        subprocess.call("python" + "question.py  ", shell=True)

    def grid_layout (self) : 
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(2)
        grid.addWidget(self.btn_newSearch , 1 , 1)
        self.setLayout(grid)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a space `"python" + "question.py"` equals `"pythonquestion.py"`

Comment: Brendan, thanks for your answer. Sorrt, but I couldn´t follow: what would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1):

If `python` is in your `PATH` environment variable, you shouldn't need the `shell=True` argument.  You also probably don't want to use `subprocess.call`, since it will block

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', 'question.py'])
```

Comment: Brendan, many thanks, that helped a lot. The close() command is not working, so the window still stays open. I have added the command line "self.btn_newSearch.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)" at the beginning, what solved the issue.Do you have any idea on how to close the window from within the def restart?

Comment: Does this command still work if the python code is turned into an executable file?